# Yammer API exporting data gives error (401) Unauthorized

Tags: yammer

We are using the Yammer API to obtain statics for various of our clients.
We have the correct access token for all of them but for some we are receiving this error: **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized..**
The zip file generated does not get downloaded.

Example call: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?model=Message&model=Group&model=Topic&model=UploadedFileVersion&model=DocumentVersion&access_token=xxxxxx-XkwP1lZFYYTF1NGrpFGmuw&include=csv&include_ens=false&since=2015-02-24T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00

When pasting the link in a new tab a file not found is shown.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be or does know another way of getting the desired data?

Comment: I'm also stuck on this, bearer token works on other end-points, although not the export endpoint. Have you found any way around this yet?